# Nifi flowfiles can be seen in Data Provenance, but aren't in the queue

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a Nifi flow like below:
ExecuteSQL -> ConvertAvroToParquet-> PutHDFS

ExecuteSQL processor retrieves data from an Oracle database.

The problem is that as soon as the process finishes, data doesn't appear in the queue. Surprisingly, I can see that Data was in fact retrieved in Data Provenance.

What could cause such a problem?

Comment: Did you check HDFS location? Try to stop PutHDFS processor and wait for data.

Comment: Yes, it is what I do, in fact. For simplification, let's assume I connected ExecuteSQL to a funnel.

Comment: Can you please show a screenshot?